# Force Order Completion

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status, edit-order

We have the following scenario to handle:

A customer orders a certain quantity of an item (let's say 20) to pick up in a specific store. Since we don't have live store inventories, there might be a back order (the store only have 15 of the 20). We invoice the customer when the store confirms that he picked some items for an order, but we only want to invoice the picked items (we do a partial invoice/payment). When a backorder happens, we want to contact the customer to offer him some solutions and one of them is that he can cancel the missing items and go in store to receive what was available. In that case, that means that we have an order of:

Order Quantity: 20
Invoiced Quantity: 15
Shipped Quantoty: 15

But the order remains "Processing" when in facts, it is complete. How can we complete this order without cancelling it because if the customer wants to return the items, we can't do it when status is cancelled? We would prefer being able to complete the order by keeping the quantities as is so we can report our Service Level.

Comment: You can offer your customer partial place order. and charge only these which qty available.

Comment: But we don't know yet if the store have the stock available when the customer place his order on the website. When the order is placed, we forward a message to the store with the order details and he confirms what he can fulfill in it and what is missing.

Comment: You need to do something like this, when customer move from cart to checkout page, at that time you need confirm into store is there all qty available or not and notify customer according to that on same screen.

Comment: There is no way we can do that because as I stated in the question, we don't have live inventory. In the solution you are proposing the customer will have to wait for someone in store to take his order and confirm stock available and then the checkout page will load (aka the customer might wait one hour or so before the checkout page is loaded).